# How to add more attribute when using html_options in Smarty

Tags: smarty3

PHP Part

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);
$texts = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$attributes = array('a1', 'b1', 'c1');
$smarty->assign('ids', $ids);
$smarty->assign('texts', $texts);
$smarty->assign('attributes', $attributes);
```

Tpl Part

```
<select name="test">
{html_options values=$ids output=$texts attribute=$attributes}
</select>
```

Result

```
<select name="test">
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

Can I add more defined attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no such functionality is available. You can generate options directly, with the code like this:

```
<select name="test">
  {foreach $ids as $id}
    <option value="{$id}" attribute="{$attributes[$id@index]}">{$texts[$id@index]}</option>
  {/foreach}
</select>
```

Or, I would suggest to make some more flexible data structure, like:

```
$data = array( 1 => array('attr' => 'a1', 'text' => 'a'),
               2 => array('attr' => 'a2', 'text' => 'b'),
               3 => array('attr' => 'a3', 'text' => 'c') );

$smarty->assign('data', $data);
```

And then using code like this

```
<select name="test">
  {foreach $data as $item}
    <option value="{$item@key}" attribute="{$item.attr}">{$item.text}</option>
  {/foreach}
</select>
```

You should add some escaping to values or use auto_escape to the values, this is just a basic idea.